# How do I overload += in Julia?

Tags: overloading, julia

I'm trying to understand how operator overloading works in Julia. The manual is quite brief, and gives `+()` as an example function, then states all the operators are overloadable with their obvious names (a list of non-obvious names is also provided).

But what about `+=?` The function `+=()` doesn't even seem to exist, nor does `+=!()` (since it is a modifying function). I frequently overload operators in C++ by defining `+=` first and then use a simple `+` based on copy and `+=`.

In my case I don't even think I need `+`, just the behavior of `+=`... I realize I could write my own modifying function but the operator syntax would be nice. (Out of curiosity, how do `*=`, `/=`, `$=`, etc work?)

Comment: += is behavior derived from the + function, so just overload +

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no `+=` function. It is simply syntactic sugar for `a = a + b`.

It is also not mutating. So `a += b` calculates `a + b` and then changes `a` to refer to the result. This means there is memory allocation for the result of `a + b`.

Comment: [there is memory allocation] => there might be need to heap allocate the result from the ``+`` operation.

Comment: @ivarne Yes, now I am wondering how to do some kind of "`+=`" that operates on large objects without memory allocation. Am I right that large immutable objects will inherently have this problem? And for large mutable objects, should I write my own mutating function rather than use an operator? Finally, surely for `Array{T,n}`, using the `+=` operator (or any element-wise operator `.*=` etc) is memory efficient??? I often deal with large matrices, tensors, etc that push memory limits and I thought Julia would be good for that type of thing.

Comment: To follow up on `Array`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656830/adding-a-scalar-to-a-matrix-efficiently-in-julia). To me it seems that `+=` *is* memory inefficient for `Array`, and that hand-written loops or broadcasting should be used instead. I'm rather surprised!

Comment: See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/249 for why `+=` does not work in-place.

Comment: Also see the InPlaceOps.jl and Devectorize.jl packages